# I didn't understand the problem about while loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

The expectation of this problem: Returns the sum of all the divisors of a number, without including it.

I have seen this problem and how it solved. But actually, I could not get it after reviewed again and again. One of the main issues, I could not understand the problem clearly. I hope someone can explain to me this problem and solution in a simple way.

Edit: I just copied my code here instead of the image. Thank you for the warning.

```
def sum_divisors(n):
  sum = 1
  # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
  div = 2
  if n == 0:
    return 0
  
  while div < n/2+1:
    if n % div == 0:
      sum += div
    div += 1
return sum

print(sum_divisors(6)) # Should be 6 (sum of 1+2+3)
print(sum_divisors(12)) # Should be 16 (sum of 1+2+3+4+6)
```

Comment: Please paste your code here, not a picture!

Comment: Post your code as text, not a screenshot of your code. Images can't be copied, compiled and debuged

Comment: You should post the code itself into your question, not an image to it.  Also what don't you understand?  Right now you're just asking someone to explain some code to you line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sum, first you have to consider only the numbers which completely divides the given number. This will range between 1 until half of the given number. For example if given number is 100, any number greater than 50 can't divide it completely, so the loop runs between 1 to 50, including 50.

Answer (score 0):

This loop checks for each number if n mod that number is 0. If n mod div == 0 it means that n is divisable by that number and it adds it to the sum. Mod gets you the reminder of the whole number division.